# Determine in ash if subdirectory exists but not under a certain directory

Tags: shell, if-statement, ash

I'm writing a script for BusyBox ash, and need to determine if a subdirectory exists so my script can display an error message.

Normally `if test -d sub/directory` would be my go-to, but the problem here is there's one folder I **don't** want to trip this logic.

I currently use `ls /folder/*/bar | grep -v foo` and parse the exit code but I know that's bad practice.

Here's what I'm looking at (bar should trip the logic, foo should not)

```
/folder/foo/bar <- this should not trip because it contains foo
/folder/dev/bar <- should trip because it contains bar but not foo
/folder/randome/name <- should not trip doesn't contain bar
```

Is there a proper/better way to do this?

Comment: _here is there's one folder I don't want to trip this logic._ - Could you add better context with a proper example folder structure?

Comment: What does it mean to "trip logic"? [do not parse ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead) I do not understand, what does it mean that you do not want to "trip logic on one folder"? Do you mean you want to  _filter out_ specific matches? The `folder/*/folder` will _not_ match any of examples - `/folder/foo/bar`  doesn't end with `folder`.

Comment: As I state in my question if a subfolder exists i display an error about a conflict, but if i'm updating I dont want my program to trigger my own error message and need to exclude my programs directory